# Help me I just got in trouble with direct address comma at work

Tags: commas

I write stuff like this:

> Karen, our team can help you.

However, in this case I wrote:

> Karen, Mike and Joe can help you.

I was trying to tell Karen that Mike and Joe could help her.  However, she read it as "Karen, Mike and Joe together could help someone else."

How was I supposed to punctuate this?

Comment: You could have added a line break after "Karen,".

Comment: I agree with @PeterShor. A line break would be best in an email, but I would probably use a hyphen in a few instances.

Comment: @PeterShor  Wouldn't a semi-colon have worked? "Karen; Mike and Joe can help you."

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I would prefer a hyphen (or dash, if it's not email) to a semi-colon. Or add a greeting and use a period: "Hi Karen. Mike and Joe can help you." Semi-colons and colons might be viewed as overly formal.

Comment: But the semi-colon is neat because it encloses and separates Karen from Mike and Joe. But whatever, you believe a semi-colon might be seen as overly formal? Never thought I'd hear an innocuous punctuation mark be accused of such a thing.

Comment: I think a colon would function better than a semi-colon there, mostly because the semi-colon would imply a continuity of thought that doesn't really exist. The colon indicates a list follows.

Comment: I don’t understand the confusion. Was not Karen the person being addressed? Did she somehow think that you were not talking to her but rather about her? If that were the case, who would the *you* turn out to be? I don’t think there’s anything wrong with your sentence in a real-world situation, because the person being address knows their own name.  It’s just being intentionally perverse to try to read this as something else. It would seem perfectly obvious if my name were Karen and you had sent this to me how to parse it out as a vocative of address and then a compound subject following that.

Comment: @tchrist ... or the reader may not be used to the Oxford comma and so the given list reads to them as though it is supposed to be a list of three.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a similar problem posed by the [serial comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma), and I generally recommend rephrasing the statement for clarity:

<sub>Original</sub>

> Karen, Mike and Joe can help you.

<sub>Rephrased</sub>

> Mike and Joe can help you Karen.

If you'd like to keep "Karen" at the beginning of the sentence, alternative punctuation can work:

<sub>Hyphen</sub>

> Karen - Mike and Joe can help you.

<sub>Em dash (punctuationally more better)</sub>

> Karen — Mike and Joe can help you.

<sub>Colon</sub>

> Karen: Mike and Joe can help you.

I don't recommend colons though as they're commonly used for dialog:

> Karen: Mike and Joe can help you.
> Steve: Thanks Karen!

Comment: @RegDwigнt, I was wondering if someone would try to correct that. I intentionally used a hyphen, because it's possible to reasonably type a hyphen in most circumstances. Although it might be more "proper" to use an em dash, it's so inconvenient that it's becoming irrelevant outside of formal publications.

Comment: It's 2014. It is trivial to type and display a dash in most circumstances. Where it still is not, the workaround is to use *two* hyphens, not one. A hyphen is not a dash. It is about as suitable a replacement for a dash as a semicolon is a suitable replacement for a colon. (Also, this has nothing to do with grammar, so your edit is incorrect in that regard as well.)

Comment: @Reg There are some who maintain that punctuation and syntax are not disjoint.

Comment: @RegDwigнt, you're right that grammatically was the wrong word. However, I do disagree with your assertion that "it is trivial to type *and* display a dash in most circumstances". It's quite trivial to *display* a dash, certainly, with UTF-8 support being what it is, but to type the dash usually requires scrounging around through lists of special characters. Some email clients make it easy to find emdash (gmail), while others (outlook) hide it behind a series of menus and dialogues. The whole point is to disambiguate the sentence.

Answer (score 7):

A colon is correct here.  You're splitting the sentence and what follows the colon is a list of things (people) you're addressing.

"Karen:  Mike and Joe can help you with this."

I'm not a fan of the semicolon for the reasons mentioned.  I think the hyphen is also perfectly acceptable, though it's less formal than a colon.  So I'd choose from the hyphen/colon according to the level of formality you're reaching for.

Comment: I don't recommend colons as they're commonly used to indicate a quote from an individual.

Comment: @zzzzBov in what contexts?

Comment: @BlackVegetable: In what contexts? zzzzBov: oh you know, when you want to show some dialog. BlackVegetable: oh, I hadn't thought of that. Thanks for being so awesome! zzzzBov: no problem, any time.

Comment: Haha, agreed.  However, in many contexts I don't think this would be a source of confusion.

Comment: A hyphen would never be appropriate here. A dash would be fine, but never a hyphen. As for dash vs. colon, they imply different things to me. If making it clear that you are addressing Karen (as an opening statement), I'd use a colon. If noting something for Karen in particular (but located in a text to be read by a group of people), I'd use a dash: “We’ll talk about the details at the meeting: I expect everyone to be well-prepared. Karen – Mike and Josh can help you get the necessary papers” for example.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, how about minus instead of hyphen? I know I'm probably getting myself in all sorts of trouble when I say this, but hyphen, dash, and minus are all the same character when used informally (`-`). There are few who are willing to spend the additional time while typing up an email to find and inject the correct symbol because it's simply cumbersome. It might be more appropriate to double the hyphen character to emulate an emdash, but either way the text reads correctly so long as you don't forget spaces. Karen-Mike could be taken as someone's name.

Comment: Well, I would be one of those people. The difference between a dash and a hyphen is quite basic and essential to me (though I admit I rarely go hunting for the correct minus sign on the rare occasion I type something that calls for it). Even typing this—on my phone, mind—I make sure to use dashes instead of hyphens. :-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Is a dash or hyphen the long one or the short one? Is minus in between?

Comment: @Mitch, dashes are longer than hyphens, but there are several kinds. Hyphen (-), en dash (–), and em dash (—) are the most common. The minus sign usually looks like either a hyphen or an en dash, but is a separate glyph (can't type it from my phone, though).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I find the three difficult to distinguish, either the marks or the words or the meaning. And I believe that other people do too. I also believe that the distinction is not important. Is there any convincing otherwise?

Comment: @Mitch, different punctuation is used for two main reasons: disambiguation and style. You want to be able to read a sentence and understand what's being said. A case where the differences are important could be "1–5" vs "1—5". The former means a range of 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. The latter could be taken as a robot named "1" responding with "5". As far as style is concerned, a typesetter may want to add flourish to the hyphen "‐" (unicode 8208), but would leave the hyphen-minus character "-" (unicode 45) plain.

Answer (score 1):

Use a colon.

> Karen: Mike and Joe can help you.

One of the functions of the colon is to set the context for the sentence that is to follow, so this usage is appropriate. It's also clear, unambiguous, and a standard in US business correspondence:

> Dear Mr. Doe:
>
> Thank you for your letter of ...

Alternatively, you can put it at the end of the sentence like this:

> Mike and Joe can help you, Karen.

But that has the disadvantage that Karen has to read to the end of the sentence before she realises that the remark is addressed to her.